# What aspects of a Web Browser should be configurable via plugins?

Tags: security, browser, plugins, interface

I'm looking at this from the perspective of the plugin developer not the user of the browser, so I'm interested in what developers think is the ideal interface for plugins to a browser.  For example:  Plugins can reorder, create and destroy Tabs, Plugins can draw behind and in front of Browser pages etc.

I'm particularly concerned about the security aspects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major thing that I look for right away is how easy it is to open a preference pane, new windows, and the security preference variables.

I also like the ability to iterate through tabs, searching through various aspects such as page currently displayed within each of those tabs.

Answer (score 2):

A web browser should have a firebug plug inn which help the developers.Concerned about security browser should block Phishing.